# Mac USB disabled due to too much power but nothing plugged in

Tags: macos, usb

Have nothing plugged in but can't get rid of the message:

> **USB Devices Disabled**
>   Unplug the device using too much power to re-enable USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

You might try examining the ports, including the SD card reader, for foreign materials, or bent terminals.

Comment: Not any I can see in fact would not have asked if that was enough to fix it. I am 66 not dead or stupid the obvious I checked

Comment: Sixty-Six?  Wow, you're almost old enough to be my father!  :)

My contribution was to also check the SD card reader port, as it's also part of the USB device tree on some systems.   

The bad news is that it's probably a short on the PCB, and likely needs replacement.

Comment: checked the sd card reader no improvement it no longer tells me it shut down USB just no longer tries